# How to get the command line arguments in MFC applications?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I wish to have a small dialog based application which is passed command line parameters, so, using VC++6 I ran the application wizard and chose an MFC dialog application.

This is not automatically equipped with command-line parameters. So I went
to MSDN to refresh my memory on these. MSDN states that all C++ programs
have either a main() or a wmain() function and that the argc, etc. arguments
go here. The application I just created does not have these.

As there is obviously a function which is the entry point to the application, can
I stick the arguments here? I did try this, but I am not convinced that I
was actually editing the correct function. (Can I find the function which
is acting as the main() function from the project settings or similar?)

Basically, how do I get my program to read command line parameters.

Also as a sideline. For a simple program, which this is, I really do not
want to make it an MFC application, and thereby over a MB in size. Are there application wizard template libraries that will allow me to make a non-MFC dialog
application?

Comment: Another question where user692270 accepts @karthik 's answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use **[GetCommandLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea)**, which returns the name of the file being executed,
followed by the arguments.

The application member **m_lpCmdLine** (used like `yourApp.m_lpCmdLine`) contains only the arguments.

There is also [CWinApp::ParseCommandLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/64c73803%28v=vs.95%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that you may find useful.

Also try the ATL COM wizard to create a non-MFC dialog application (chose the .exe option, not .dll).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see [CWinApp:ParseCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64c73803.aspx). Also take a look at the [CCommandLineInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaydx040.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

In MFC applications, the entry point function is 'initInstance()', like `main()` or `wmain()`. Use `CWinApp::m_lpCmdLine` in `initInstance()` to access the command line.

Answer (score 1):

To get the raw command line use the following code (will work on any Win32 / MFC application):

```
TCHAR *pCommandLine = ::GetCommandLine(); 
int nArgc = 0;
LPWSTR *pArgv = ::CommandLineToArgvW(pCommandLine, &nArgc);
```

nArgc should be 1 when no arguments given and larger than 1 when there are. Then, pArgv[1] will be the first argument, and so on...