# Provide parameter to MFC GUI application from command prompt

Tags: visual-c++, cmd, mfc

I have a MFC GUI application. Now I have to execute this exe from commmand prompt with parameter.I need to know where I have to change the code in order that it use parameter from cmd.

When I debug the code the control comes here:

```
CConnectDlg::CConnectDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CConnectDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CConnectDlg)
    m_ul_Timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
}
```

So I think I have to change here.
Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the command line arguments in mfc applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562877/how-to-get-the-command-line-arguments-in-mfc-applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the command line anywhere in your application, calling [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx). To split the command line into individual arguments, you can call [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use the global [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) symbols, that provide the same information, and are available anywhere in your program as well.

Comment: Yes, I had find it on google.btw thanx. now I have to send data to command prompt. Any idea.

Comment: @vikky: If you have a new question, click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button, after you have done enough research to assess, that this question hasn't been asked before.